# Batch create folders?

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, powershell

I'm looking for a way to batch create a folder followed by sub-folders.

I'm looking at something like

```
c:\users\user\desktop\sample\1
c:\users\user\desktop\sample\2
```

etc.

Any ideas?

I'd prefer .cmd/PowerShell methods to do so.

If there's a way to do so via a terminal, I'll be happy to attempt any ideas/solutions by booting into a Linux live disc via usb.

Comment: If you prefer PowerShell why are there more references to batch? Powershell Scripts are easy to write if thats what you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command md like so:

```
for /l %a in (1,1,2) do md "c:\users\user\desktop\sample\folder %a"
```

This would create the two folders as in your example.

Comment: I also need to create directories with spaces in the name. How would I go about something like: c:\users\user\desktop\folder one or c:\users\user\folder 1 and so on?

Comment: @Chris0089 I've made the modifications as requested.

Comment: @AlexanderCeed `FOR %F IN ("folder one","folder two") DO (md %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%F)`

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script will create directories with numerically sequential names.

```
function New-SequentialDirectory
{
Param
(
    [string] $Path = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).Path,
    [UInt32] $StartAt = 1,
    [UInt32] $EndAt
)

$Path = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).Path
if (-not (Test-Path -PathType Container $Path))
{
    $exception = New-Object System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException "The specified directory does not exist: $Path"
    throw $exception
}

Write-Debug "Path: $Path"
foreach($number in $StartAt..$EndAt)
{
 $itemPath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $number
 New-Item -Path $itemPath -ItemType Directory   
}
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Creates a series of directories with numerically sequential names.

.PARAMETER Path
The path at which the sequence should be created. This must be an existing directory.
.PARAMETER StartAt
The number at which the sequence should start. This value must be positive and may be greater than the value of the EndAt parameter.
.PARAMETER EndAt
The number at which the sequence should end. This value must be positive and may be less than the value of the StartAt parameter.

.EXAMPLE
New-SequentialDirectory -StartAt 1 -EndAt 10

 Directory: C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\test


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                             
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                             
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            1                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            2                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            3                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            4                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            5                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            6                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            7                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            8                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            9                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:18 p.m.            10                                                                                                                                               

This example shows the creation of a sequence of ten folders in the current directory.

.EXAMPLE

New-SequentialDirectory -StartAt 10 -EndAt 1


Directory: C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                             
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                             
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            10                                                                                                                                               
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            9                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            8                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            7                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            6                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            5                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            4                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            3                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            2                                                                                                                                                
d----        5/10/2014  2:57 p.m.            1                                                                                                                                                

This example shows that the EndAt parameter can be less than the StartAt parameter.
#>   
}
```

To use the code below you need to:

1. Copy the code above into a file named `New-SequentialDirectory.ps1`
2. Add the function to your session with this command<sup>1</sup>
   `. <path-to-New-Sequential-Directory.ps1>`
3. Call the function. A few examples of how to do this are provided in the help for the command which is available via the `Get-Help New-SequentialDirectory -Examples` command once the function is in your session.

<sup>1</sup> Step two may fail because by default PowerShell doesn't let you run scripts from files. To fix this you need to change the execution policy to something slightly less restrictive. For more information on this see `Get-Help about_Execution_Policies`